# JS console any option from if...else

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I´ve started with JS, and I cannot get print in console, one of the following options in this exercise. The selected option depends on the input of the user with a prompt, but after reviewing everything I cannot debug it, Any help please?? Thank you!!

```
let guests = prompt('How many people are coming to your wedding?');

function getPrice(guests) {
  let cost = 0;

  if (guests <= 50) {
     cost = 4000;
  } 
  else if (guests >= 51){
      cost = 10000;
  }
  else if (guests >= 101){
      cost = 15000;
  }
  else (guests >= 201){
      cost = 20000;
  }    
  return cost;
}
let price = getPrice();

console.log ('Your wedding will cost '+'$'+price+' dollars');
```

Comment: `else (guests >= 201){` ... missing a `if` in there?

Comment: of course, if guests = 201 ... then `guests >= 51` so ... you'll never get further than that `if` in that case ... try using <=50, <=100, <=200 in that order and remove the `(guests >= 201)` just have the `else`

Comment: Also you do not need to split strings for every atomic part. `'Your wedding will cost $'+price+' dollars'` will work - a more modern method is using backticks (template literals) `\`Your wedding will cost $${price dollars\`` where the `${}` is wrapping the variable

Comment: Thanx Jaromanda! I fixed it, but a question...Why should I include a "if" inside of --else (guests >= 201){cost = 20000;} -- if this statement closes the function???

Comment: Because you have a statement after. IF/ELSE works like this `if (a) then a; else if (b) then b; else c` -  You have `if (a) then a; else if (b) then b; else (c) then c;` - missing an if

Comment: @AlvaroGarzónDelgado Here are the solutions for problems with your code: 1) For the last condition, use `else if`, and if you want to use `else`, then remove condition. 2) `getPrice` is a function which accepts a parameter. And you're passing nothing while calling it. And that is why, 0 cost is being returned. The solution is to either pass `guests` as argument while calling it, or remove the `guests` parameter at all, so that it uses global variable. :)

Comment: SO `else cost = 20000;` will make sense

Answer (score 1):

the main problem you encounter is that in your function definition you have an argument `guests` but you run the function without it `getPrice()` so guests will be undefined because you defined it for function scope.

you have two options now,

1: just remove the argument from defintion and it will take the value of the "global scope" variable `guests`

`function getPrice() {...`

2: just pass guests like
`let price = getPrice(guests)`

the if else part i guess will be easy to fix then ;)

here you see working option 1:

```js
let guests = prompt('How many people are coming to your wedding?');

function getPrice() {
  let cost = 0;

  if (guests >= 201){
      cost = 20000;
  } 
  else if (guests >= 101){
      cost = 15000;
  }
  else if (guests >= 51){
      cost = 10000;
  }
  else {
     cost = 4000;
  }
  return cost;
}
let price = getPrice();

console.log ('Your wedding will cost '+'$'+price+' dollars');
```